Gelfand's Calculus of Variation Sec 13 and Problem 2
In Gelfand & Fomin Calculus of Variations in the chapter 3 problem 2 he asks

Derive the formula for the general variation of a functional of the form
$$
J[y] = \int_{x_0}^{x_1}F(x, y, y')dx + G(x_0,y_0,x_1,y_1).
$$

An this question relates back to the Sec 13. Under the equation (4), which reads
\begin{equation}
\tag{i}
\Delta J = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \left[ F(x,x+h, y'+h') - F(x,y,y') \right] dx + \int_{x_1}^{x_1 + \delta x_1} F(x,x+h, y'+h') dx -  \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + \delta x_0} F(x,x+h, y'+h') dx 
\end{equation}
a Taylor expansion is performed and equals to
\begin{equation}
\tag{ii}
\int_{x_0}^{x_1}  \underbrace{\left[ F_y-\frac{d}{dx} F_{y'}\right] h(x) dx}_{(I)} + \left.F\right|_{x={x_1}}\delta x_1 + \underbrace{F_{y'}h\left.\right|_{x={x_1}}}_{(I)} - \left.F\right|_{x={x_0}}\delta x_0 - \underbrace{F_{y'}h\left.\right|_{x={x_0}}}_{(I)}
\end{equation}
I see that the elements $(I)$ is the result of integrations by parts but the other 2 terms I suppose come from the Taylor expansion of the first part (in the book) from equation $(ii)$
$$
\text{Euler-Lagrange base integral} + \left.F(x,y,y')\right|_{x=x_1}\delta x_1 - \left.F(x,y,y')\right|_{x=x_0}\delta x_0
$$
Question 1
This is the step that I'm not getting, expanding $F(x,y,y')$ around some $\delta$ would result in $F(x,y,y') + F_x\delta x + F_y \delta y + F_{y'}\delta y'$, right ? How can recover the final result in equation $(ii)$?
Question 1.2 ) I found this notation rather difficult to follow, could the same result be obtained using Gateaux derivative (with the book's trick of sliding the integration interval)?
Question 2
On the same line, how would one expand $ G(x_0 + \delta x_0, y_0 + \delta y_0, x_1 + \delta x_1, y_1 + \delta y_1)$?
